# Using grep to find all substrings of strings that may contain special characters

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, regex

I am trying to use grep to find the string "crk" in a file. I know the string exists in a c source file in the form

```
kop.crk_op = CRK_MOD_EXP;
```

However, when I search using

```
 grep -rnw --include '*.c' '.' -e "crk"
```

I get an empty result. The line

```
 grep -rnw --include '*.c' '.' -e "crk_op"
```

works just fine, but that really isn't helpful to me. I assume the '_' character is somehow messing up my search. How can I modify my approach to match all strings of which "crk" is a substring, even when the '_' character is present, or any other character for that matter?

Edit: It seems I got a bit trigger happy on this post. The command

```
grep -rnw --include '*.c' '.' -e "[^ ]*crk[^ ]*"
```

seems to work. Alternatively, can someone explain why the extra wildcards are needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-w` option makes grep look for words, so it will show `crk` when surrounded by non-word characters. From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
-w, --word-regexp
      Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
      words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
      at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
      constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
      of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
      Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
      underscore.
```

`_` is a word character, so `crk_op` will not match `crk` with `-w`.

The convoluted regex `"[^ ]*crk[^ ]*"` works because it allows any number of non-space characters between the word boundaries that grep requires.

Just do:

```
grep -rn --include '*.c' . -e crk
```

You don't need to qoute `.` for the current directory there.

Comment: Hmmm, so '_' is a word character but '[', for example, is not. How odd...

Comment: @user3813122 not particularly so, if you know a but of programming history. `_` has been allowed in variable names since around the time grep was created (at least), and it's only natural to see a variable name as a word.